# Space of derivations that give a Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, jacobian

Find an n dimensional space L of derivations, such that [l, l'] = 0 for l,l' in L. Any help or hints would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Fact}$: Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ it's Lie algebra. Then if $G$ is abelian, then so is $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $G = \mathbb{R}^n$.